# Проставить точки между двумя span

Tags: html, css

Есть [такая](https://jsfiddle.net/fdv4zweL/) разметка:

```css
.left {
  float: left;
}

.right {
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<span class="left">соль</span>
<span class="right">2гр</span><br>
<span class="left">сахар</span>
<span class="right">2гр</span>
```

Нужно динамически поставить между двумя `span` точки. Не могу сделать статично, так как не знаю заранее длину слова. Как это лучше реализовать?

Comment: Можно использовать бэкграунд с повторением по горизонтали

Comment: Точки, это по сути border-bottom:1(2,3,4)px dotted #333. Просто между ними блок с этим бордером.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JS тут вообще не нужен, - можно [обойтись](https://jsfiddle.net/fdv4zweL/1/) одним CSS.

**Код:**

```css
.row {
  width: 100%;
  display: table;
  table-layout: auto;
  padding-bottom: 0.5em;
}
.left, .right {
  width: auto;
  display:table-cell;
  margin-bottom: -0.5em;
}
.left {
  float:left;
  padding-right: 0.25em;
}
.right {
  float:right;
  padding-left: 0.25em;
}
.separator {
  border-bottom: 1px dotted black;
  display: table-cell;
  width: inherit;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <span class="left">соль</span>
  <span class="separator"></span>
  <span class="right">2гр</span>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <span class="left">сахар</span>
  <span class="separator"></span>
  <span class="right">2гр</span>
</div>
```

**Пояснения:**

- Родительский элемент шириной 100% заставляет строку растянуться на всю ширину.
- `display: table;` и `display:table-cell;` заставляют браузер воспринимать элемент, как таблицу или ячейку таблицы, соответственно.
- `width: inherit;` - говорит элементу наследовать ширину родителя (100%). Обычно, это заставило бы сепаратор занять всю ширину родителя, но в таблице, при отсутствии явно заданных строк, браузер размещает все ячейки в одну строку, ограничивая сепаратор доступной (не занятой другими ячейками) шириной.

Answer (score 3):

Пусть метод немного варварский, но все же. Суть в оборачивании спанов одной строки дивом и присвоения псевдоэлемента с повторяющимся по горизонтали фоном - картинкой точки и пробела. Если размер шрифта постоянный, можно обернуть сразу все спаны одним дивом, тогда высота картинки должна быть равна `line-height`.
http://codepen.io/malginovdesign/pen/NNaajv?editors=1100
Как уже написали выше, вместо `background` можно использовать 
  `border-bottom: 1px dotted;` - работает великолепно.

```css
.left{
  left: 0;
}
.right{
  right: 0;
}
.left, .right {  
  background: #f5f5f5;
  z-index: 2;
  position: absolute;
}
.row {
  position: relative;
  background: #f5f5f5;
  height: 1.2em;
}
.row:after {
  content:'';
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0.3em;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: url(https://box.everhelper.me/attachment/435173/c5e2217d-449a-4bfd-b77c-09ce861ed3c5/552479-3lax16SYwGefxRbJ/screen.png) repeat no-repeat;
  background-position-y: bottom;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <span class="left">соль</span>
  <span class="right">2гр</span>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <span class="left">сахар</span>
  <span class="right">2гр</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Много вариантов перепробовал, сделал лучше:

https://codepen.io/maks-t/pen/gOQZdyb

```css
* {
  border: 1px solid gray;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}


.center {
  margin: 0 auto;
  max-width: 900px;
}

ul {
  list-style: none;
  
}

li {
 display: flex;
 justify-content: flex-start;
 align-items: center; 
 width: 100%;
 padding: 0.4rem;
 
 font-size: 20px;
 font-style: normal;
 font-weight: 400;
 line-height: 30px;  
}

span:first-child:after {
  content: '...........................................................................................................................................';
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: clip;
}

span:first-child {
  white-space: nowrap;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  overflow: hidden;
}

span {
  padding: 0.2rem;
  max-width: 100%;
  
  color: black; 
}
```

```html
<div class="center">
  <ul class="projects-detailed__spec_desc">
    <li><span>Форма</span><span>Название___</span></li>
    <li><span>Форма</span><span>___Название</span></li>
    <li><span>Форма</span><span>___Название___</span></li>
    <li><span>Форма</span><span>Название</span></li>
    <li><span>Форма</span><span>Название</span></li>
</ul>
</div>
```